# How to make VSCode Autocomplete React Props to String instead of number?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

**Context:**

I'm using `react-native` with the package `native-base`.
Native base has typescript and my VSCOde autocompletes these prop names.

**The Problem**

I type in `justif..` --> This then gives me the suggestion for "justifyContent" --> When I then press enter the prop gets filled out but with this: `justifyContent={}` with the cursor between the curly braces.

Most of the time in this package you want to provide string names. This happens since the typescript type it excpects is either number or many strings (enums). I expect vscode always chooses the number type, hence the curly braces.

**I want vscode to always autocomplete this like so: `justifyContent=""` with the cursor between the "".**

This happens not just for this prop but for almost all props that can also take numbers (for example fontSize prop).

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: This drives me nuts too. Did you find a solution? The options of `typescript.preferences.jsxAttributeCompletionStyle` don't have a "quotes only" mode, which would make this possible.